# MongoDb get all match data from deeply nested array document

Tags: mongodb, nested

How to get education data (include the parent) for each family member in families that has year 2006? Supose I have data in mongodb:

```
{
  "name": "Families",
  "size": 3,
  "families": [
    {
      "name": "Johny's Family",
      "size": 2,
      "family_member": [
        {
          "name": "Ruben",
          "age": 22,
          "education": [
            {
              "school": "Edward Academy",
              "year": 2003
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Hana",
          "age": 20,
          "education": [
            {
              "school": "Edward Academy",
              "year": 2006
            },
            {
              "school": "Nanyang University",
              "year": 2012
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Boy's Family",
      "size": 1,
      "family_member": [
        {
          "name": "Boy",
          "age": 23,
          "education": [
            {
              "school": "Broklyn Academy",
              "year": 2003
            },
            {
              "school": "Home School",
              "year": 2006
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have try to get it using plain find function in mongodb but the result is not realy I wanted. this is my mongo script:

```
db.getCollection('tester').find(
{
    "name":"Families",
    "families.family_member.education.year":2006
},
{
    "families.$.family_member.education.year":1
}
)
```

Can anyone suggest the best method to get the data become something like this:

```
{
  "name": "Families",
  "size": 3,
  "families": [
    {
      "name": "Johny's Family",
      "size": 2,
      "family_member": [
        {
          "name": "Hana",
          "age": 20,
          "education": [
            {
              "school": "Edward Academy",
              "year": 2006
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Boy's Family",
      "size": 1,
      "family_member": [
        {
          "name": "Boy",
          "age": 23,
          "education": [
            {
              "school": "Home School",
              "year": 2006
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use JavaScript code to process your data because mongodb return data in unit of Document.
process "families" field like this:

```
doc.families.map((family)=>{
    family.family_member = family.family_member.map((member)=>{
        member.education = member.education.filter((edu)=>edu.year==2006);
        return member;
    });
    return family;
})
```

Comment: I'm sorry TsingJyujing, but I need the mongo script instead of using javascript. maybe if u have the mongo script u can post it here.

Comment: The reason why we using Javascript has written above, it's hard to write a mongoscript to done this. Or you may define your user functions in mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Using aggregation pipeline we can get this result. To achieve this use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/). $unwind need to be used twice since we have deeply nested arrays

```
db.tester.aggregate([
   {$unwind:"$families"}, 
   {$unwind:"$families.family_member"}, 
   {$unwind:"$families.family_member.education"}, 
   {$match:{"families.family_member.education.year":2006}}
])
```

Comment: your answer is slightly different with the expected result. But I can get the result after modified your answer (a little). thanks. here is the modified script: 
`db.getCollection('tester').aggregate([
   {$unwind:"$families"}, 
   {$unwind:"$families.family_member"}, 
   {$unwind:"$families.family_member.education"}, 
   {$match:{"families.family_member.education.year":2006}}
])`

Comment: Glad, it helped and you got the expected result. I have modified the answer, so that it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. You can get expected result using `aggregation` and you have to use `$unwind` then `$match` and `$group`

```
db.CollectionName.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$families"},
  {$unwind: "$families.family_member"},
  {$unwind: "$families.family_member.education"},
  {$match: {"families.family_member.education.year": 2006}},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {$first: "$name"},
      size: {$first: "$size"},
      families: {$push: "$families"}
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change your query like below, It should work:-**

```
db.getCollection('tester').find({"families.family_member.education.year": 2006},{"families.family_member.education.year":1})
```

**OR**
If you want to print whole things, use only this:-

```
db.getCollection('tester').find({"families.family_member.education.year": 2006}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I think its not the right answer @gajju_15, your answer looks almost exactly with my first query, and it cannot give the desired output actually.